# pelican: How to embed html and javascript in markdown

Tags: python, html, markdown, pelican

I want to embed a few html elements and javascript in a blog post. This is my markdown file.

```
Title: Foo
Tags: Bar

Some Content here 

        <div id="foo">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bar.js"> </script>
```

But pelican is wrapping the html tags in a `pre`. So the code is not getting executed.

I'm using the Markdown library installed from `pip install Markdown`, version 2.3.1

I checked the [docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.3.0/), but to no avail.

How to avoid this from happening, either through markdown or in a pelican setting?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the reason its not working is that you've indented your code, which means that it gets inserted as a `<code>` block in the HTML, according to the Markdown spec: [daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode)

Comment: There should not be "probably" :)